# Is there a blogger tag to get the URL of a Page's main image?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, blogger

In blogger, for posts, we can use the `data:blog.postImageUrl` data 'tag' to include an image for Open Graph/Twitter cards meta tags like so:

```
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' property='og:image'/>
```

Unfortunately though this doesn't work for Pages. Is there a tag that does the same for pages? I've tried a few but I'm pretty much guessing. Strangely, the information is available in the Atom feed under `media:thumbnail`.

Alternatively, are there any tricks/hacks we can use to see all available tags? Can we loop over them somehow?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've found a workaround - use `<meta expr:content='"http://example.com/blog-images/" + data:blog.pageId' property='og:image'/>` and host the image on your own domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data:post.firstImageUrl` tag but its shortcoming is that it will only work inside the `<b:widget>` tag of `type='Blog'` inside a `<b:loop>` iterating over `values='data:posts'` (You will be able to find references of this tag in any Standard Blogger template)

```
<b:if cond='data:post.firstImageUrl'>
    <meta expr:content='data:post.firstImageUrl' name="twitter:image"/>
</b:if>
```

Due to this, it will only work correctly for Twitter Cards but won't work for Open Graph tags as they require the meta tags to be present inside `<head>`